# how i can checking the duplicate links with php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a database like this :

database name : link

```
|  id |  username                      |  linkterm  |   linkurl     |
|  1  |   [COLOR="#FF0000"]a[/COLOR]   |  google    |   google.com  |
|  2  |   [COLOR="#FF0000"]a [/COLOR]  |  yahoo     |    yahoo.com  |
|  3  |   [COLOR="#0000FF"]c[/COLOR]   |  google2   |   google.com  |
|  4  |    d                           |     ask    |   ask.com     |
```

i want checking the duplicate links when my user want adding new link . for example if my user want adding the google.com my php codes should printing a error that this link is duplicate links. i have to google.com links in my database i don't have any problem this item but i want don't have any other google.com in " a " user .

i wrote this code but not working :

```
$oldlink = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(linkurl) 
FROM `link` where `username`=a 
AND
`linkurl`=google.com");

if($oldlink>0){echo 'duplicate links';}else{echo 'links submitted';}
```

please help me .

thank you.

Comment: You're not treating your values as strings. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html

Comment: Add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` and you'll see the errors. You have enough to debug your code.

Comment: Plus, why in the name of *whoever your higher power is*, are you using `[COLOR="#FF0000"]a[/COLOR]` inside a table? You'll never find anything like that; not with what you're using now. You'll need more than an MySQL function to achieve this. `LIKE` "might" work; but not 100% sure.

Comment: no i dont use [color] in table

Comment: If it's not in your table, you should remove it from your question's code then; it's deceiving/misleading.

Comment: thank you my problem solved . very very thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Most likely because of the first comment; right? ;-)

Comment: You may as well delete the question then, since it has been resolved in comments.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly the mysql_query function will return a resource type ,so your judgement is incorrect . see the php manual

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-db-query.php
```

in your case you need use mysql_fetch_assoc or mysql_fetch_row to process the result.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($oldlink); 
// or                                                                                                                       
$row1 = mysql_fetch_row($oldlink);
```

at the same time suggest your give the COUNT(linkurl) an alias if you used mysql_fetch_assoc .

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(linkurl) as linkurl FROM `link` where `username`=a AND `linkurl`=google.com");
```

Comment: This will still fail. Plus, the OP said it was solved; because of what I told them in regards of how they were treating their values.